# Correctly use Association in Mathematica to Apply Labels to Vectors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a matrix that holds multiple vectors with associated labels.  The matrix looks something like this:

```
inputseq2s={{0,2,4,6}->"A",{9,7,6,5}->"B",{5,6,4,3}->C}}
```

I then map a function across the matrix like this:

```
outtable2=Map[{#[[2]],iterfunc[#[[1]]]}&,inputseq2s];
```

But the output looks like this:

```
{{A,{0,1,0,1}},{B,{0,0,1,1}},{C,{0,0,0,1}}}
```

And I need it to look like this:

{{0,1,0,1}->"A",{0,0,1,1}->"B",{0,0,0,1}->"C"}

But I have thus far been unsuccessful at figuring out how to make that happen.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the full code.  I did not include it previously because I thought it might muddy the waters, but here it is:

```
iterfunc=Function[seq2,coltot=Length[Partition[seq1,window,offsetwindowseq1]];
rowtot=Length[Partition[seq2,window,offsetwindowseq2]];
outlabels=Table[wordseqname<>"("<>ToString[If[x<2,x,((x-1)*offsetwindowseq1)+1]]<>"-"<>ToString[((x-1)*offsetwindowseq1)+window]<>")",{x,1,coltot}];
dist1=Tuples[{Partition[seq1,window,offsetwindowseq1],Partition[seq2,window,offsetwindowseq2]}];
outtable=Partition[Table[CanonicalWarpingDistance[dist1[[i,1]],dist1[[i,2]],Automatic,{"SlantedBand",bandwidth},Method->{"MatchingInterval"->"Flexible"},DistanceFunction->distfunc],{i,1,Length[dist1]}],coltot];
normfunc=Function[x,x/window];normtable=Map[normfunc,outtable];
test=Function[x,If[x<=threshold,1,0]];
outtable2=Partition[Map[test,Flatten[normtable],1],coltot];
Total[outtable2]];
```

Comment: I edited it now.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the elements of `inputseq2` list of rules to a list, with the label first and the output of `interfunc` second.

You may want something like this instead:

```
outtable2 = Map[Rule[interfunc[#[[1]]], #[[2]]] &, inputseq2s]
```

Both `inputseq2` and `outtable2` are lists of rules, not associations.